# Create a function with variable but fixed number of arguments

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

Is there any possibility to create a function with variable but fixed number of arguments i.e. not a vararg function? I mean something like this.

```
(bind n 42)
(lambda (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) (do_something x_1 x_2 ... x_3))
```

The only thing I know, which creates new functions with different argument count, is 'curry', but I don't see how to iterate this principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`case-lambda`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-6.html#node_idx_262) in Scheme implementations that have it.  It should be avialable with all r6rs implementations too.  Also, some implementations have a way to define optional arguments, instead of the manual tweaking of a rest argument.